# How to share code between micro services?

Tags: architecture, microservices

For example, I have a project which has 4 micro services: client-web, admin-web, client-api, admin-api.

These four micro services should share one DB code,  should I make the DB code as a submodule of git and use it in each micro service?

does it against micro service principle?

Comment: It will probably depend on the language used which solution works best, and still it may be very opinion based. But I don't see how sharing a piece of code would be against micro service principle. After all, they each need to connect to the database, so why would you duplicate the code?

Comment: By creating a library?

Comment: The 4 micro services by name seem more like client server architecture rather than micro services. Typically, each micro service is designed with its own entity/DB access code. Maybe the DB code you have is a micro service on its own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a library.
2. Version the library with semantic versioning and create a package using the package management functionality of your environment (e.g. Nuget if you're on .NET).
3. Include the package as dependency in the micro services.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should be careful making a shared library and include it in your microservices because it can give you a point of coupling, meaning that if you have to make changes to the library, you might have to change all your services, and then you loose one of the benefits of this architecture -deploying small services without deploying the whole application.

I think a better approach is to make it a microservice on its own.

Comment: "if you have to make changes to the library, you might have to change all your services", yeah, sorry, but no, that's why it's called a "shared" library, not "static" ;)

Comment: I think it is always a bad idea to have a "persistence" microservices. This is a microservices anti pattern, that leads to a microservices monolith.

Answer (score 0):

Micro services should own their own DB logic. So for each peach of your DB, you should have a micro service that communicates with it. Cross cutting concerns should be either in their own service which calls the others or in the service that best represents the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an http interface for the db which can communicate using REST APIs with the other microservices. Then you can check user permission to understand which client can access a given resource.